# ¿Cómo añadir valores str a una columna en función de los valores str de otra?

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un dataframe con la siguiente columna y los siguientes valores (pongo ejemplo, tengo 2.495 tipologías diferentes):

```
  Categoria
0 'Ciencias computacionales, electronica; sistemas'
1 'Salud, psicología'
2 'Ciencias computacionales, matemáticas'
3 'Sociologia, ciencias políticas'
4 'Antropologia'
5 'psicologia social'
```

Me gustaría clasificar estas categorías por las ramas científicas más amplias en una nueva columna y que quedara algo así:

```
 Categoría                                                      Rama
0 'Ciencias computacionales, electronica; sistemas'           'Ciencias naturales'
1 'Salud, psicología'                                         'Ciencias de la salud'
2 'Ciencias computacionales, matemáticas'                     'Ciencias naturales'
3 'Sociologia, ciencias políticas'                            'Ciencias Sociales'
4 'Antropologia'                                              'Ciencias Sociales'
5 'psicologia social'                                         'Ciencias Sociales'
```

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de automatizar este proceso.

De los 2.495 valores únicos que hay en la variable categoría, solo hay 4 clasificaciones posibles en la variable rama ('Ciencias Sociales', 'Ciencias Naturales', 'Ciencias de la Salud' y 'Arte y Humanidades').

El criterio para etiquetar cada registro lo pongo yo (no existe en ningún sitio donde pueda encontrar esa relación), por ello entiendo que lo tendré que etiquetar yo manualmente. Solo me gustaría algún truco para hacerlo de la forma más rápida.

Muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo!

Comment: Coloca una muestra de tu dataframe como codigo, y el dataframe que esperas como salida.

Comment: Haz una lista de palabras claves por rama. Por cada item examinas sus palabras claves para definir que rama asignarle. Si no encuentra ninguna, asignale una Rama por defaul (la más popular).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma *sencilla* es hacerlo como dijo CandidMoe en su comentario, es decir, hacer un lista con las palabras claves, sin embargo yo utilizaré un diccionario. Para poder iterar en un DataFrame usaremos la función `apply()` y le pasaremos como función una lambda, Luego haremos el ciclo `for` correspondiente y asignaremos el nombre según corresponda.

**creamos el diccionario con palabras claves**

```py
categorias = {"Ciencias naturales":["Ciencias", "sistemas"], "Ciencias de la salud":["salud", "psicología"], "Ciencias Sociales":["social", "políticas","Antropologia"]}
```

**código**

```py
df["rama"] = df["Categoria"].apply(lambda x:[c for c in categorias for n in str(x).split() if n in categorias[c]][0])
print(df)
```

Aqui hemos iterado en la columna `Categoria` lo que nos devuelve cada valor de la columna, eso se lo pasaremos a la `lambda` y hacemos la compresión de lista, esta compresión no devuelve un único valor, sino varios y por eso elegimos el primer elemento `[0]` pero en caso no haya valores dará un error.

**resultado**

|  | Categoria | rama |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Ciencias computacionales, electronica; sistemas | Ciencias naturales |
| 1 | Salud, psicología | Ciencias de la salud |
| 2 | Ciencias computacionales, matemáticas | Ciencias naturales |
| 3 | Sociologia, ciencias políticas | Ciencias Sociales |
| 4 | Antropologia | Ciencias Sociales |
| 5 | psicologia social | Ciencias Sociales |

Otra forma podría ser crear una función que se encarge de catalogarlo con un poco más de precisión y en caso no haya coincidencias escogerá el que mas se acerque

```py
def verify(x):
    x = x.split() #separamos el string y retorna una lista
    ramas = {} #diccionario vacio
    for v in categorias: #recorremos las categorias
        for r in x: #recorremos la lista 
            pnt = 0 #establecemos un puntaje
            if r in categorias[v]: 
                pnt+=1 #sumams 1 al puntaje en caso la palabra se encuentre
            ramas[v] = pnt #agreamos al diccionario
    rama = max(ramas.items(), key= lambda x:x[1])[0] #obtenemos el maximo
    return rama #retornamos el valor
```

Y simplemente lo usaremos así:

```py
df["rama"] = df["Categoria"].apply(lambda x: verify(str(x)))
print(df)
```

**resultado**

|  | Categoria | rama |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Ciencias computacionales, electronica; sistemas | Ciencias naturales |
| 1 | Salud, psicología | Ciencias de la salud |
| 2 | Ciencias computacionales, matemáticas | Ciencias naturales |
| 3 | Sociologia, ciencias políticas | Ciencias Sociales |
| 4 | Antropologia | Ciencias Sociales |
| 5 | psicologia social | Ciencias Sociales |

Si deseas puedes agregar más palabras claves al diccionario

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si `x` no está en el diccionario?

Comment: @CandidMoe en el primer caso lanza un error, en el segundo escoge la palabra con mayor puntuación, si todos son 0 escoge la primera, aunque también se puede usar un valor por default, como `sin rama` o cualquier cosa

Comment: Muchas gracias! El primero no me funciona pero el segundo va a la perfección. Se lo agradezco enormemente, un saludo!

Comment: El único problema que veo es que las palabras claves no me funcionan porque en mi base de datos cada categoria es un string completo, por ejemplo: "Sociologia, antropologia". Para que me funcione correctamente necesito que en cada resgistro estos valores se separen quedando en la misma columna tal que así: "Sociologia", "antropologia". Cómo puedo conseguir esto? Muchas gracias de nuevo!

Comment: @Alba puedes separar el string por comas o guiones o lo que sea conveniente tal de que siempre queden palabras separadas

Answer (score -1):

Puedes crear una funcion para ello. Por ejemplo, la funcion `get_rama()` te devuelve la categoría correcta de la siguiente forma: Si en la columna `Categoría` aparece la palabra "Salud", entonces la Rama será "Ciencias naturales", si aparece la palabra "Sistemas", entonces será "Arte y Humanidades". Y así con las demás.

```
def get_rama(df):
  for index, categoria in enumerate(df['Categoria'].to_list()):
    categoria = categoria.lower()
    if 'sistemas' in categoria:
      df.loc[index, 'Rama'] = 'Arte y Humanidades'
    elif 'sociologia' in categoria or 'antropologia' in categoria:
      df.loc[index, 'Rama'] = 'Ciencias Sociales'
    else:
      df.loc[index, 'Rama'] = 'Sin Definir'
```

Comment: `sistemas` solo se encuentra en la primera fila

Comment: ¿De verdad propones agregar dos líneas de código por cada nueva palabra que quieran catalogar?

Comment: @CandidMoe Creo que si la categoría tiene palabras clave dentro de su descripcion, esta se puede usar para categorizar de forma mas rapida.. ahora bien, no habia leido que son 2495 categorias diferentes.